# Exact inversion of matrix complexity (by Gaussian elimination)

Tags: matrix

I would like to check if what I have done is correct. Please, any input is appreciated.

**Problem statement:** Consider a non-singular matrix $A_{nxn}$. Construct an algorithm using Gaussian elimination to find $A^{-1}$. Provide the operation counts for this algorithm.

**My attempted algorithm and operations count:**

Let $[A|I]$ be an augmented $n$ x $2n$ matrix.

INPUT: number of unknowns and equations n, augmented matrix

OUTPUT: $A^{-1}$, provided that the inverse exists

STEP 1: For $i=1,\dots,n-1$ do STEPS 2-4

STEP 2: Let $p$ be the smallest integer with $i \leq p \leq n$ such that $a_{pi} \neq 0$. If no integer $p$ exists then output ('no unique solution exists'); STOP

STEP 3: If $p \neq i$ then perform $E_p \leftrightarrow E_i$

STEP 4: For $j=i+1, \dots, n$ do STEPS 5-6

STEP 5: Set $m_{ji}=a_{ji}/a_{ii}$.

STEP 6: Perform $(E_j - m_{ji}E_i) \rightarrow (E_j)$

STEP 7: If $a_{nn}=0$ then output NO UNIQUE SOLUTION EXISTS and STOP

STEP 8: For $i=n-1,n-2,\dots ,1$,
For $j=i+1,i,\dots ,1$ do STEPS 9 and 10

STEP 9: Set $m_{ij}=a_{ij}/a_{jj}$

STEP 10: Perform $(E_i - m_{ij}E_j) \rightarrow (E_i)$

STEP 11: for $i=1, \ldots, n$, do $E_i/a_{ii} \rightarrow E_i$

STEP 12: OUTPUT $A^{-1}$ and STOP.

**I am getting the operations count as follows:** A total of $(2n^3+9n^2+n)/3$ multiplications and divisions and a total of $(2n^3+6n^2-8n)/3$ additions and subtractions for a grand total of $4n^3/3 + 5n^2 - 7n/3$ operations. **Does this sound about right?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a non-singular matrix A. Construct an algorithm using Gaussian elimination to find $A^{-1}$
I had the same problem and [did it](http://avrabie.blogspot.com/2014/09/blog-post.html) In python:

```python
#Helper functions:
def check_zeros(A,I,row, col=0):
"""
returns recursively the next non zero matrix row A[i]
"""
if A[row, col] != 0:
    return row
else:
    if row+1 == len(A):
        return "The Determinant is Zero"
    return check_zeros(A,I,row+1, col)

def swap_rows(M,I,row,index):
"""
swaps two rows in a matrix
"""
swap = M[row].copy()
M[row], M[index] = M[index], swap
swap = I[row].copy()
I[row], I[index] = I[index], swap

# Your Matrix M
M = np.array([[0,1,5,2],[0,4,9,23],[5,4,3,5],[2,3,1,5]], dtype=float)
I = np.identity(len(M))

M_copy = M.copy()
rows = len(M)

for i in range(rows):
index =check_zeros(M,I,i,i)
while index>i:
    swap_rows(M, I, i, index)
    print "swaped"
    index =check_zeros(M,I,i,i) 

I[i]=I[i]/M[i,i]
M[i]=M[i]/M[i,i]   

for j in range(rows):
    if j !=i:
        I[j] = I[j] - I[i]*M[j,i]
        M[j] = M[j] - M[i]*M[j,i]
print M
print I  #The Inverse Matrix
```